# Count the elements in a csv file with python

Tags: python, csv

I got a question regarding counting the number of times a specific number belongs to a specific element.

Let me explain it better by use of an example. First I got this situation within my csv file:
[image: Capture from my csv file]

What I want is that within Python I need to have the following results:

- 1 with 1200 is 4 (times visible)
- 1 with 5600 is 5 (times visible)
- 2 with 1400 is 3 (times visible)
- 2 with 1600 is 2 (times visible)

Can anyone help me getting this result?

Code that I have untill now is just loading the csv:

```
with open('calculate_ids.csv') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Counter mapping the rows to tuples:

```
from collections import Counter
with open('calculate_ids.csv') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
     counts = Counter(map(tuple,reader))
```

That Counter dict will count how many times the each pairing appears.

To see the counts just iterate over `.items` and you will see each pairing as the key and the count as the value:

```
for k, v in counts.items():
    print("{}  and {} are paired {} time(s)".format(k[0], k[1], v))
```

Comment: Thanks! :) I am going to try this out!! Will reply if it worked! Thanks! :)

Comment: @Rotan075,  no worries, the only issue is if the numbers can appear it either column, do the numbers in each column ever overlap?

Comment: The csv file does not contain like: 1,1 (column1,column2). like the same value for colum1 and column2 does not appear. The scenario of having: 1,2 and later on the csv file 2,1 does occur. Is that a problem?

Comment: @Rotan075, it depends on what you want to do, are 1,2 and 2,1 the same or considered a different pairing?

Comment: You have to see that for example 1 have a connection with 2. And 2 have a connection with one. So if you want to see the value for 2 it must output 1. so I would say they are not the same.

Comment: If they are not the same then we are fine the code will work as is.  Anyway if you did want to consider them the same considering there are only two items sorting would be the simplest approach  `counts = Counter(tuple(sorted(row)) for row in reader)`, then they will always appear in the same order.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  I will mark your answer! :)

Comment: Still got one question left. Your code does the work! Thanks for that! But what I do not understand is that it does output the same order as within my csv file. So if for example I have the following situation: _1 with 7000 paired 14 times_ and after that I got _1 with 2 paired 14 times_ then it still can occur that first I got 1 with 7000 paired 14 times and (instead of expecting 1 with 2 paired 14 times) 2 with 1 paired 14 times. Do you know why this is?